# Native Audio in OSX

Tags: macos, audio, native

Basically my question is: if I have some raw LPCM data (NOT AN AUDIO FILE) that I want to play how would I go about writing that data to playable audio buffers and then beginning playback in C/C++? I realize that C might not be possible but my understanding is that the whole OS X native audio system is based on C++ so I don't think I should have to use objective C. I have dealt with AudioQueue services but I have not been able to find a method to directly write audio data to an AudioQueueBuffer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Traditionally, you'd have done this by attaching a render handler to an input pin on either one end of a audio unit graph or the removeIO/AUHAL node.   The APIs for this are mostly in C.  More recently, the (AVFoundaton)[https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188] APIs provide higher level functionality for the same kind of thing.